# Determine tables / query from Missing Join Predicate event

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiler

On SQL Server 2008, in the profiler, I have a Missing Join Predicate event class that happened at 3:30am StartTime.  How do I get more information?  What query was being executed, or tables were being joined?